# How long ago did protein synthesis from DNA start?

Tags: dna, protein-expression

How long ago did DNA start to include sequences that code for protein?

Comment: where have you looked for information on this? online, google, wikipedia?

Comment: Protein isn't synthesised from DNA it's synthesized from RNA.

Comment: I've googled it first yes, I could not find it. And yes, I realize that protein get synthesized from RNA, but the protein is coded in the DNA. My question is, when did DNA code start to contain information on the proteins that are the result of gene expression. Sorry if my formulation caused confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two questions being asked here.

1) When DNA was used to encode RNA via DNA dependent RNA polymerase
It is uncertain if the Last Universal Common Ancestor (LUCA) had this enzyme. There is some debate.

Also some  DNA polymerases of family A, B are structurally related to RNA polymerases https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK6360/. So DNA may have come after RNA. The switch to DNA has been proposed to be a result from a reaction to the evolution of RNAse.

2) When RNA was used to encode protein via ribosome
LUCA has ribosome. So LUCA had proteins made from RNA
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2926754/

And LUCA has been estimated to have appear around 3.5-3.8 billion years ago. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Last_universal_common_ancestor

Comment: Please define the abbreviation LUCA in your answer.

Comment: Last Universal Common Ancestor.

Comment: I worked that out, but I shouldn't have to. Define it in your answer so that everyone knows. The use of undefined acronyms is lazy and inconsiderate and decreases the value of an answer.

Comment: DNA and RNA... which actually stand for Deoxyribose Nucleic Acid and Ribose Nucleic Acid.

Comment: I am afraid that this will not wash. More people know what DNA and RNA are than know what it stands for. As you are not willing to clarify your answer, then I shall your do it for you, although I hardly think it worth it for such a poor question. Also the last common ancestor hasn't been around since 3.5-3.8 billion years ago — that would imply it is still around. It was thought to have lived then.

Comment: Thank you very much JayCkat, I found your answer to be clear and satisfactory. Sorry we did not meet your requirements David :/